# How to get plugin name from plugin file location

Tags: plugins, functions, updates

I'm running this code to tell me what plugins need updating:

```
$update_plugins = get_site_transient('update_plugins');
```

Here is an example return:

```
Array
(
    [login-lockdown/loginlockdown.php] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3760
            [slug] => login-lockdown
            [new_version] => v1.5
            [url] => http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/login-lockdown/
            [package] => http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/login-lockdown.1.5.zip
        )

)
```

From that it doesn't tell me the name of the plugin that needs updating. Is there a WordPress function that you can feed the plugin file name like: `ogin-lockdown/loginlockdown.php` and return the plugin name? In this case I'd want `Login LockDown` to be returned.

Comment: Link to the plugin that displays a table listing all plugins that need an update in the admin footer: https://gist.github.com/995560

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll have to work via [`get_plugins()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L197). It will return a list of all plugins in your plugin folder, indexed by plugin location - which is the same as your array index. This is also [what the plugin administration table uses](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-plugins-list-table.php#L52).

If you only need the data from one file you could also call [`get_plugin_data()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.3/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L9) directly. `get_plugins()` basically just calls that function in a loop, and caches the result.